# Block IP/Domain using powershell

Tags: windows

Is it possible to block a ip address and website using powershell in windows 7 ?

Hosts file is not an option for me as I want to block IP address so that windows cant connect to that website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that is possible, but I know you can use the firewall in Windows 7 to block outgoing connections to an IP address.  Create an outgoing rule (I think the Port type will work) and once completed go to properties and on the Scope tab enter the remove IP address that you want blocked. The Action must be set to "Block the connection".

You can block for all ports or selected list of ports.  For eample, you can block port 80 for HTTP traffic while still allowing other traffic to pass.

Comment: Windows Firewall was the choice ! ... In custom rules I could actually type the IP and it can disable / allow that rule on the fly ...thanks...